# How to keep relative links in GitHub subproject consistent in npmjs.org interface

Tags: github, markdown

The code of the npm package I'm developing belongs to a bigger repo, which contains a lot of different stuff. There's a `README.md` file with relative links to the documentation contained in the same folder as the package.

When I'm viewing this `README.md` file in GitHub interfaces, the links are resolved with

```
https://github.com/<company>/<repo>/blob/master/<path-to-my-project>/docs/
```

prefix, which is the correct and expected behaviour.

But npmjs.org is resolving these links with

```
https://github.com/<company>/<repo>/blob/master/docs/
```

so as you can see the subproject part of path is just ignored.

The question is, what is the best version to circumvent this problem? As far as I understand, `npmjs.org`relies on the `repository.url` property from the `package.json`. Should I just point to my subproject there ignoring the fact that the actual repo has a different physical address? Will it help?

Or should I add just absolute paths?